# Impedir scroll cuando un div se muestra

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

Estoy intentando impedir el scroll cuando se abre un div (del site de membresía Memberful) a modo de overlay. Adjunto el código actual:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
if ($(".memberful-overlay").is(':block')) {
$(document.body).addClass("memberful-no-scroll"); }
else {
$(document.body).removeClass("memberful-no-scroll"); }
});
```

También he utilizado la etiqueta ":visible" y "body" en vez de document.body, pero tampoco ha funcionado.

El Css es:

```
.memberful-no-scroll {
overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, debes crear un [mre] para poder entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Hola, @Excorpion. Soy totalmente nuevo por aquí y, tras leer la información del enlace, no me queda muy claro qué más información necesitaría aportar para ayudaros a entender mi problema. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Para dar a entender un error, o algo que no logras, es necesario replicar el código, de este modo VER que sucede y leer tu código. Para ello se crea el [mre] un código ejemplo, del error que estas teniendo, un extracto. Ahora mismo hay un jquery, y un css... pero nada de html con el que corra y se ejecute

Comment: Vale, entiendo. ¿Ayudaría si os adjunto el enlace del site donde intento añadir ese jquery?